# UIGestureRecognizer Method Clarification

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

Hi any one can explain me, what are the cases can i use the following UIGestureRecognizer Methods.

```
1. - (BOOL)canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)preventingGestureRecognizer
   - (BOOL)canPreventGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)preventedGestureRecognizer

2. - (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer

3. - (BOOL)shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer
   - (BOOL)shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer
```

Kindly give the use case of all this three methods, if u have any example kindly comment here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: kindly read the class reference related to the gesture recognizer. here is the link https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Xcode Monkey, i am implementing my own custom gesture, one is for panning the view in horizontal, another one gesture for showing the details. detail gesture will get detect only the user move the finger from top to bottom certain distance and either from there left or right, so when i start move top to bottom pan getting detected, while i start either left or right, pan should get fail, but not detail. how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer%3a).

**canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:**
Overridden to indicate that the specified gesture recognizer can prevent the receiver from recognizing a gesture.

**canPreventGestureRecognizer:**
Overridden to indicate that the receiver can prevent the specified gesture recognizer from recognizing its gesture.

**requireGestureRecognizerToFail:**
Creates a dependency relationship between the receiver and another gesture recognizer.

**shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:**
Overridden to indicate that the receiver should be required to fail by the specified gesture recognizer.

**shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:**
Overridden to indicate that the receiver requires the specified gesture recognizer to fail.

Answer (score 2):

All those methods simply establish dependancies of different types between different recognizers. Certain gesture recognizers may use similar gestures, and these are typically set up so that one takes precedence over another.

For example, a scrolling gesture and a swipe gesture are similar in that they both involve a touch moving in a particular direction, so you might set up the swipe recognizer such that it requires the scrolling recognizer to fail before the swipe can be recognized. Or, you could set them up so that the scrolling recognizer prevents the swipe recognizer from being activated while the user is scrolling.